# FIFO with poor placed ADJQTY SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, partition, fifo

I have this data, It should work according to FIFO math, but the problem I see with it and can't resolve is that in the end we need to have results split by warehouses and plants, so IN stuff should count according to it's warehouse and plant and part and bin.

But ADJQTY stuff, should be calculated only by Part but in the order it was made. I tried calculate them separately, then adding to each other, tried numerous cte solutions with sort and reverse sort calculation, LEAD and LAG partition. but the fact that adj and IN calculation should count differently brakes my brain.

```
create table #test
(plant nvarchar(10), warehouse nvarchar(50),part nvarchar(10), bin int, trantype nvarchar (10), trannum int, trandate date, qty int)

insert into #test values
('plant1','warehouse_4','part1',1,'IN',1,'2016-05-20',3),
('plant1','warehouse_4','part1',1,'IN',2,'2016-11-02',2),
('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'IN',3,'2017-03-10',5),

('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'ADJQTY',4,'2017-03-30',-1),  
---the programm wrote them as warehouse 3 and plant 2, but this still should work as FIFO and take them from  the firs row (warehouse4, plant1)
('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'ADJQTY',5,'2017-04-27',-1),  
---the programm wrote them as warehouse 3 and plant 2, but this still should work as FIFO and take them from  the firs row (warehouse4, plant1)
('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'ADJQTY',6,'2017-07-11',-2),
--so at that point we should have plant1 warehouse4 qty 1, plant2 warehouse3 qty 5

('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'IN',7,'2017-08-18',4),
---after that we have plant1 warehouse4 qty 1, plant2 warehouse3 qty 9

('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'ADJQTY',8,'2017-08-31',-1),
--- this is still should ignore it's plant and warehouse and correct qty on warehouse4,makint it zero, so we have only 9 on warehouse3

('plant1','warehouse_4','part1',NULL,'ADJQTY',9,'2017-09-29',-5),
---this one decided to write to itself warehouse4, plant1, and eat the bin num, but according to FIFO and partnum, it now should take from warehouse trannum3, from warehouse3, plant2, making it 4 there

('plant2','warehouse_3','part1',1,'ADJQTY',10,'2017-10-13',-2),
---after this, we have 2 qty on warehouse3

('plant1','warehouse_4','part1',1,'IN',11,'2018-10-10',4)
---so we have  
--plant2 warehouse3 qty 2
--plant1 warehouse4 qty 4

select * from #test

drop table #test
```

[logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtfXj.png)

[][1]

Comment: What is "ADJQTY"? My [Google-fu](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3A+ADJQTY) doesn't give me a meaningful answer, and what ever the acronym means seems important here.

Comment: hello! it is just adjusment to stock quantity, not selling, but just got rid of. Don't really have any special meaning, it is only the problem, that the programm that make them don't have warehouse and plant in them, so it put them randomly anywhere and this makes probles with calculating...

Comment: Could you show the expected values or what you're trying to do? I think what you're looking for is SUM(qty) OVER(ORDER BY trandate) but what do i know

Comment: it can't just sum(qty) because I need FIFO math with ADJ taking out from the first IN warehouse and plant

Comment: the final result is given in comments - after all the math we should have qty 2 in warehouse 3 and ty 4 in warehouse 4
If i just sum everything it would be just the math for Part, but I need to include warehouses and plants

Comment: That's where OVER ORDER BY comes in, it allows to aggregate by FIFO. For warehouses, you can use PARTITION BY

Comment: For ADJ, you can just summarize them ahead of time

Comment: hm, yeah..if count all the adj beforehead, and start with them, and then select only pas 0, it works on this example. thank you very much, I will try to implement it on rather more difficult excercise)) but thank you for new idea!

Comment: But how can I SUM ADJ before with warehouses? If I do partition by all part for adj, then i don't have info on warehouses qty, if I do math with adj ahead of time but partition by warehouse, summ of adj won't roll past first warehouse...